# Scope not updating inside a function in a different state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two states using the same controller, when I trigger a function from State 1, I want it to go to state 2 and changes its title as well, here's my code:

```
$scope.page2Title = "Testing"; 
$scope.aFunction = function(){
              $scope.page2Title = "Hello"; 
              $state.go('eventmenu.page2');
};
```

But page2's title is not updated to "Hello", it is still "Testing".  I also tried $scope.apply() but doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you please paste the full code, including where `page2Title` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$scope.page2Title` is a local scope to the controller.  It would **not** be available when the new view is loaded.

Using `$rootScope` or a service would allow the data to be persistent between views.  I think for what you are doing `$rootScope` would be appropriate.

If you were looking to store business logic or data I would recommend using a service.

*[About $rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)*